# When using cast - error: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

Duration column in the table is given with 'varchar' data type. It contains decimal values. So I am trying to cast varchar to float/numeric/decimal/double/double precision. But none of those works. why is it not working?

select runner_id,
sum(case when **cast(duration as decimal)** <> '' then 1
else 0 end) as delivered, count(order_id) as total_orders
from t_runner_orders
group by runner_id

Comment: And why do you need to cast it to decimal if all you do is check if it is not empty!?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean with 'But none of those works'. Are there any errors!? If so, then what kind of errors?

Comment: No checking null is one kind. Further down my case I need to do calcualtion with duration column. I am getting a error:  Invalid input syntax for type numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because your duration column contains values which cannot be cast to a numeric type. The specific value throwing the error is an empty string. Also, you shouldn't be comparing a numeric type to an empty string.

Also, if you're comparing a varchar column to a character value in your CASE statement, why are you trying to cast it to a numeric type at all?

For what you're doing here, I would just write it as `CASE WHEN duration <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

And if you do need to cast it to a numeric type at some point, the way to do that would be something like `CASE WHEN duration = '' THEN NULL ELSE cast(duration AS DECIMAL) END` (asuming that empty strings are the only values in your column which cannot be cast to decimal)

Answer (score 0):

You can translate '' to null using `NULLIF` in the cast.

```
cast(nullif(duration,'') as decimal) is not null
```

However this will not solve you basic problem which is *"varchar' data type. It contains decimal values"* NO it does not it contains a string which **you hope are decimal values**, but nothing prohibits putting 'zero.zero' into it - distinctly not a decimal value. I will go @AdrianKlaver one step further.  
3. The only long term solution change the column type to numeric.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are doing the `CAST` before the `<> ''`. The `cast` fails as there are empty strings in the field. You have several choices:

1. Use `NULL` instead of '' in field.
2. Do `duration <> ''`
3. Last and probably the best long term solution change the column type to numeric.